# Appium works very slow on screen having dynamic mobile elements

Tags: appium

I am working on automating an Android app. We have a screen that has a table wherein the cell values keep on changing in seconds. I have observed that it takes more than a minute for AndroidDriver to execute a single action.
I have read on some other forums about this and got to know that this is how the UiAutomator2 works and it has nothing to do with Appium. UiAutomator2 waits for elements to come to a static state and then performs the actions.
Since the dynamic elements on the screen are unavoidable, is there any workaround for this to make Appium scripts execute with good speed? Let me know what you all think of this. I will really appreciate your comments on this. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-server/issues/379 But I am still facing slowness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right. It has nothing to do with Appium itself, but with UiAutomator. UiAutomator takes accessibility snapshots only when the application is in idle mode and the framework itself is not optimized for cases when there are constant changes in the page view. As a workaround, try to play around with `waitForIdleTimeout` such as setting it to zero or try with setting the `disableWindowAnimation` to true in the desired capabilities.

You could also try with running the following commands:
`adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0`
`adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0`
`adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0`

As a last resort, you could ask for the developers to provide you with a special build that has the animations removed in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my specific problem was that the mobile app had a timer in the UI, that was changing its value every second.
Looks like the driver was waiting for the DOM to become idle, so it was SUPER slow because of that.

This simple command fixed the issue for me:

```
# Python code
driver.update_settings({"waitForIdleTimeout": 0})
```

**Additional references:**

- https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/settings/update-settings/
- https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14155